# GitHub API Authentication for GraphQL: How do I publish my app publicly if it needs authentication?

Tags: api, github, graphql

Per the GitHub V4 API, using GraphQL requires authentication. The GitHub API V4 docs state the following:

> Warning: Treat your tokens like passwords and keep them secret. When working with the API, use tokens as environment variables instead of hardcoding them into your programs.

This is understandable. However, I'd like to publish my source code on GitHub and host the app on GitHub Pages.

**Question**: If I set up the authentication token as an environment variable, how will the actual app itself, once published, be able to use GraphQL to authenticate? Won't it break?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "host the app on GitHub Pages"? AFAIK Github Pages hosts only static files. There are no environment variables to set. Is it all Javascript?

Comment: Oof, yeah, I'm a total noob. All I've hosted so far _is_ a static site/resume/blog. I'm working on a React project that's purely Typescript and was hoping publishing it on GH Pages would've been easy.

Comment: [But apparently it's possible](https://medium.com/the-andela-way/how-to-deploy-your-react-application-to-github-pages-in-less-than-5-minutes-8c5f665a2d2a)

Comment: Sure, you can push whatever HTML, CSS, and Javascript you like; they're just files and they get executed by the browser. But it has no authentication tokens. Use [OAuth](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using server-side code, set the environment variable and be done with it.

If you're using GitHub Pages, [you can't host a server-side app](https://help.github.com/en/articles/what-is-github-pages).

> GitHub Pages is a static site hosting service designed to host your personal, organization, or project pages directly from a GitHub repository.
>
> GitHub Pages is a static site hosting service and doesn't support server-side code such as, PHP, Ruby, or Python.

It's only for static files: HTML, CSS, Javascript. These are executed in the browser. There is no environment variable to set. No place to hide secrets from the user.

Instead, build it as an [OAuth App](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/). OAuth allows the user to authorize your web site to use their account to access the Github API. This is how Github's own GraphQL API Exporer works.